# bootstrap cols without padding, 1px horizontal line appears

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

I'm doing website and I want do perform a nice portfolio in bootstrap without padding between columns. I set cols 25% width, but website shows 1px horizontal line on a webpage

That's a [code I passed](http://paste.ofcode.org/xkigeHWmEjnK3BSKDT5peN):

And that is [Result](http://studioleopard.pl/event4you/realizacje)

Login: Testowy
Password: T3st123

*Do you know how to solve this problem?*

Comment: Where is that 1px horizontal line exactly? I am unable to see.

Comment: Yes i run newest Google Chrome: 41.0.2272.101 m

That is how 1px horizontal line looks like: http://awesomescreenshot.com/06e4rjydf4
It is between 2nd and 3rd column

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer by my own.

I had to change left atrubute from 302px, 604px etc to 0%, 25%, 50% and 75%.
and to delete overflow: hidden; element from .overlay-wrapper